# ¿Cómo acceder a respuesta de función Ajax?

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, webforms

Ejecuto una función Ajax y obtengo esto:

```
{d: "{"Id":null,"Result":false,"Description":"Autentificacion Fallida"}"}
```

¿Cómo puedo acceder a sus propiedades?

Funcion:

```
function LoginUser() {
    var user = $('#user').val();
    var password = $('#password').val();
    var flag = $('#check:checked').val();
    if (user === '' || password === '' || flag !== 'on') {
        alert('Todos los campos son obligatorios');
        return false;
    }
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "Default.aspx/LoginUser",
            data: JSON.stringify({ user: user , password: password}),
            contentType:"application/json; chartset=utf-8",
            datatype: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data.Description);// UNDEFINED
            },
            complete: function () {
                console.log('LOGINUSER');
            }
        });  
}
```

Codigo C#:

```
  [WebMethod]
        public static string  LoginUser(string user , string password)
        {
            ResponseWM response = new ResponseWM();
            password = EngineTool.ConvertirBase64(user + password);
            EngineDb Metodo = new EngineDb();
            bool result = Metodo.LoginUser(user, password);
            if (result)
            {
                response.Description = "Autentificacion Exitosa";
                response.Result = true;
                System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["User"] = user;
            }
            else
            {
                response.Description = "Autentificacion Fallida";
                response.Result = false;
                System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Session["User"] = null;
            }
            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(response);
        }
```

Comment: Cuando sale de su metodo, el string es formado como JSON, pero la firma es "string".  Me pregunto si tiene que cambiar de public static string a public static Json?  Tiene que decir al navigador que lo que sigue actualmente es JSON y no es un string que aparece como JSON.  Tiene sentido?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

pude solucionar de la siguiente manera :

```
   **var dtP = JSON.parse(data.d);**
            if (dtp.Description === 'Autentificacion Exitosa')
                alert(dtp.Description);
            else 
                alert(dtp.Description);
```

Comment: Marca la respuesta como aceptada haciendo click en el check verde del costado izquierdo.

Answer (score 1):

Intenta pasar tu data de respuesta por la funcion `var dataParseada =  JSON.parse(data);`  y ahora si podrás utilizar las propiedades como `dataParseada.Description`.

Comment: Ya no es necesario ya que le esta indicando que recibirá un json como respuesta en `datatype : "json"`.